# phpmyadmin show all tables not separated into views and tables

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

How can I make phpMyAdmin 4.0.8 behavior like it used to listing all tables so it doesn't do this:

[image]

I have been reading all the old posts and so far in my config I have added all of these but still have to keep clicking the expand tables every 2 minutes.

```
$cfg['ShowPhpInfo'] = true;
$cfg['ShowAll'] = true; // Enable display all the rows
$cfg['MaxRows'] = 50; // Maximum number of rows to display
$cfg['MaxDbList'] = 1000; // Maximum databases displayed per page
$cfg['MaxNavigationItems'] = 1000; // Maximum navigation items per list
$cfg['MaxTableList'] = 1000; // Maximum tables displayed per page
$cfg['NavigationTreeDBSeparator']  = ''; // Disable prefix removal
$cfg['NumRecentTables'] = 100; // Number of recently used tables. Set this to 0 (zero) to disable the listing of recent tables.
$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 604800; // Prevent timeout for a week 
$cfg['NavigationTreeEnableGrouping'] = false; // Group the databases based on a common prefix in their name 
$cfg['NavigationDisplayLogo'] = false; // Hide logo
$cfg['NavigationTreeDisplayItemFilterMinimum'] = 9999; // Minimum number of items (tables, views, routines and events) to display a JavaScript filter box above the list of items in the navigation tree.
$cfg['NavigationTreeDisplayDbFilterMinimum'] = 9999; // Minimum number of databases to display a JavaScript filter box above the list of databases in the navigation tree.
```

Comment: phpmyadmin version 4.0.8

Comment: Why not downgrade? `:P` Could be as stupid, but any specific reason for upgrading pMA?

Comment: @praveen-kumar-purushothaman perhaps security?! all websites I have are continuously scanned for pMA folders these days.

Comment: @machineaddict Maybe... I don't even remember answering this! LoL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you wish to set [`NavigationTreeEnableGrouping`](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_NavigationTreeEnableGrouping)`= false;`

Comment: Thank but I tried this and it only effected grouping databases with the same prefix. Not related to grouping Tables and Views which is my main issue

Comment: Oh, of course you're right, I misunderstood. In my quick test I didn't have any views and it expands right away. At the moment, there's no way I know of to automatically expand these, but you might try opening a feature request (http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?atid=377411&group_id=23067&func=browse) to automatically expand all available views and tables.

Comment: I couldn't actually find anywhere to open a feature request on that page

Comment: Sorry, guess I should have thought that through. https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/feature-requests/new/ but you'll need to log in to Sourceforge for it to work properly.